# Rails ActiveRecord relationships for has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What would the correct relationships in Rails be for this setup:

```
users
  id
  name
  email

roles
  id
  name

permissions
  id
  name

users_roles
  id
  user_id
  role_id

roles_permissions
  id
  role_id
  permission_id
```

I then have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => 'users_roles'
end

class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, :join_table => 'roles_permissions'
end
```

Is this correct? As when I try and access:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.roles
```

I get the error: `undefined method 'roles' for #<User:0x007fc0176c6b08>`

So it seems the relationships are not setup properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So it seems the relationships are not setup properly.

1. You didn't add the association :)

   ```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, :join_table => 'users_roles'
   end
   ```
2. join tables naming convention is alphabetical - it should be `roles_users` - if you change it, you won't have to specify the [`join_table` option](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many).

Comment: Ah so that needs adding to both User and Role. HABTM?

Comment: @Cameron yea, you should add the association on both sides